# Error while executing MySQL queries on MySQL server version 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am trying to execute a query on MySQL server but it is throwing below errors. It was working fine on MySQL server 5.1 but now I am using 8.0

Query

```
SELECT group1s.group_id, group1s.customer_id
 FROM icm_b_instance_group1s as group1s inner join icm_b_instance_groups 
as groups on group1s.group_id = groups.group_id
 where group1s.is_active = 'Y' and groups.is_active = 'Y';
```

> [Code: 1064, SQL State: 42000]  You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'groups on group1s.group_id =
>   groups.group_id' at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MySQL 8.0 Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

> GROUPS (R); added in 8.0.2 (reserved)

So `groups` which you use as an alias is a reserved word and cannot be used in versions 8.0.2+

Comment: It can be used, if you use backticks around it. Although it is better to rename alias to something else.

Comment: Reserved words should not be used in any case to avoid such errors and confusion. The problem is with the new  reserved words that each new version may add. So renaming all old uses is the best option.

Comment: Thank you very much @forpas